# Multiple mysql queries ordered by frequency

Tags: mysql

- Name         Age     Work     Eyes
- John       young  home       black
- Mike    young     factory   blue
- Irvin    old          home       black
- Marie  young   home       blue
- Teddy    old       factory  green

In html multiple checkbox form search term1=young, term2=home, term3=blue

```
//display all combination order from first in table<br>
$sql = mysql_query("select(Name) from Table where Age = '$term1' or Work = '$term2' or Eyes = '$term3'");
```

I need to display in order by frequency. In my situation first (on top of results) must be Marie

Which functions and how to do this?

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are [in the deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: How is Marie related to frequency?

Comment: By frequency or by percentage of matching terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     my_table
WHERE    (Age = 'young')
      OR (Work = 'home')
      OR (Eyes = 'blue')
ORDER BY (Age = 'young')
       + (Work = 'home')
       + (Eyes = 'blue') DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e9fa/1/0).

Comment: It's works. Thanks. But I have a new problem. I put Limit 1 for most common coincidence, but if there are more results with equal number of coincidences I want to show all of them.<br> Any suggestions?